# select all checkbox and have the value of checked checkbox to 'on' jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/7ddqdpmk/3/) is my fiddle for selecting from 3 checkbox. I want to have the value of selected checkbox to `on` while the unchecked are value `off`. I write the default value to `off` and tried to change the value of checked to `on`. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: In the future please include relevant code in the question it self, or better still use StackOverflow's code snippet feature, the `<>` button in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `if ($("input[name='resolution[]']:checked")) {`, `$("input[name='resolution[]']:checked")` will return a jQuery object which will contains all the selected checkboxes with name `resolution[]`

You need

```
$('#res').click(function () {
    var resolutiontemp = {};
    var resolution = [];
    $("input[name='resolution[]']").each(function () {
        this.value = this.checked ? 'on' : 'off';
        var resolution = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
        resolutiontemp[resolution] = this.value;
    })
    resolution.push(resolutiontemp);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resolution));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qoa94hng/)

Comment: i just have one question why would the condition `if` return the status of first element if i have it in an `each` funtion? just wondering so i wont commit same mistake

Comment: @HogRider see the update... in the each loop you need to use `this` to refer to the current element

Comment: @HogRider also you may really not have to update the checkbox value - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qoa94hng/5/

Comment: let me check up the lastest fiddle and if i have question i will raise it asap

Answer (score 2):

Use below code Snippet to achieve expected result.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="res1" name="resolution[]" class="resolution" value="off"/><span>res 1 </span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="res2" name="resolution[]" class="resolution" value="off"/><span>res 2</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="res3" name="resolution[]" class="resolution" value="off"/><span>res 3</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall" name=""/><span>Select All</span></td>

            </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#selectall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
    var resolutiontemp = {},resolution = [];
    if(this.checked) { 
        $("input[name='resolution[]'").each(function() { 
            this.checked = true;
            $(this).prop('value','on');
            var resolutionval = $(this).val();
            var resolution = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
            resolutiontemp[resolution] = resolutionval;
        });
    }else{
        $("input[name='resolution[]'").each(function() { 
            this.checked = false;
            $(this).prop('value','off');
            var resolutionval = $(this).val();
            var resolution = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
            resolutiontemp[resolution] = resolutionval;
        });         
    }
    resolution.push(resolutiontemp);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resolution));
});
```

[Fiddle Result](http://jsfiddle.net/7ddqdpmk/7/)